# Apache Nutch 1.15 Solr 7.7.0 indexing failed DocValuesField is too large, must be <= 32766

Tags: java, indexing, solr, nutch

I’m trying to crawl some sites with Apache Nutch 1.15 and indexing them to search with Solr 7.7.0, following this tutorial https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial. I'm using cygwin64 on windows 10.

Every time I run a command I receive this message (I did some research and it seems the it cannot be solved, am I right?), but beside that it seems to work.

```
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by 
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil 
    (file:/C:/cygwin64/home/apache-nutch-1.15/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.4.jar) to 
    method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
    org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal 
    reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future 
    release
```

The problem is that when I try to index using this command

```
$ bin/nutch solrindex crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

I get this error message:

```
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20190218180046.
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20190218180429.
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20190218180720.
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20190219113805.
Indexer: starting at 2019-02-19 16:18:44
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
No exchange was configured. The documents will be routed to all index 
writers.
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
    type : Type of the server. Can be: "cloud", "concurrent", "http" or "lb"
    url : URL of the SOLR instance or URL of the Zookeeper quorum
    commitSize : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
    auth : use authentication (default false)
    username : username for authentication
    password : password for authentication


Indexing 591/591 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Indexing job did not succeed, job 
status:FAILED, reason: NA
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:152)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:244)
```

And in the log file of Solr I find this error:

```
2019-02-19 16:18:51.668 ERROR (qtp2031588185-21) [   x:nutch] 
o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception 
writing document id
http://apache.org/foundation/records/minutes/2010
/board_minutes_2010_06_16.txt 
to the index; possible analysis error: DocValuesField "content_str" is too 
large, must be <= 32766
at 

org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc
(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:243)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd
 (RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
(…)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "content_str" 
 is too large, must be <= 32766
 at 
 org.apache.lucene.index.SortedSetDocValuesWriter.addValue
 (SortedSetDocValuesWriter.java:82)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.indexDocValue
 (DefaultIndexingChain.java:616)
 at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc
 (DirectUpdateHandler2.java:235)
 ... 71 more

 2019-02-19 16:19:06.612 INFO  (commitScheduler-13-thread-5) [   ] 
o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start 
commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=false,waitSearcher=true,
expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
2019-02-19 16:19:06.612 INFO  (commitScheduler-13-thread-5) [   ] 
o.a.s.u.SolrIndexWriter Calling setCommitData with 
IW:org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter@2d18ed13 commitCommandVersion:0
2019-02-19 16:19:06.671 INFO  (commitScheduler-13-thread-5) [   ] 
o.a.s.s.SolrIndexSearcher Opening [Searcher@28296264[nutch] realtime]
2019-02-19 16:19:06.676 INFO  (commitScheduler-13-thread-5) [   ] 
o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 end_commit_flush
```

I cannot find any solution to this problem. Someone can help me?
Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error is not coming from Nutch, but it is thrown on the Solr side. What is more suspicious is that the `content_str` field is not provided directly by Nutch. Try setting `docValues` to `false` in either the `fieldType` or the `field`. Doc values provide certain benefits but storing larges amount of data (like 32k) will have some negative performance impact on the long run. You should use a stored field instead. Or change the type of this field to be tokenized.

More of details about doc values can be found [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/docvalues.html).